# Layered Bar chart with d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar chart inside bar chart otherwise called as Layered Bar Chart. My sample code is as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <script>
        var dataArray = [10, 20, 40, 60];
        var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500);

        var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect").data(dataArray).enter().append("rect").attr("width", function(d){
            return d * 10;
        }).attr("height", 30).attr("y", function(d, i){
            return i * 35;
        }).attr("fill", "blue").attr("fill-width", "green");

        canvas.append("text").text(function(d){
            return d;
        }).attr;



        var dataArray1 = [5, 10, 20, 30];

        var bars1 = canvas.selectAll("rect").data(dataArray1).enter().append("rect").attr("width", function(d){
            return d * 7;
        }).attr("height", 20).attr("y", function(d, i){
            return (i*35) + 5;
        }).attr("fill", "red").attr("fill-width", "black");;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here bars and bar1 are bar charts drawn on svg container. My problem is when lengthier bars are visible, smaller bars are not vissible. But I am trying to place smaller bars inside the lengthier bars so that it may look like the image below.[image] .

But I am not able to do so. Commenting the lengthier bar chart code shows me smaller bars. Any help on this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution, see [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xoqed/1/edit).

Problem was that there were no change in length of array so `enter()` had nothing to append. The first array has to be expanded so new elements can be created.

```
var dataArray1 = [5, 10, 20, 30];
var offset = dataArray1.length;
dataArray = dataArray.concat(dataArray1);

var bars1 = canvas.selectAll("rect")
//    .data(dataArray1)
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr("width", function(d){
            return d * 7;
        })
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("y", function(d, i){
            return ((i - offset)*35) + 5;
        })
        .attr("fill", "red");
        //.attr("fill-width", "black");
```

**Update:** Another solution with less changes adds `class` attribute do differentiate between base and added bars. See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xoqed/2/edit).

```
var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr('class', 'base')
        ...

var dataArray1 = [5, 10, 20, 30];

var bars1 = canvas.selectAll("rect.addon")
    .data(dataArray1)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr('class', 'addon')
        ...
```

Comment: Note: I don't know what is `fill-width` for so I commented it out.

Comment: Just a small detail: the multiplier for width (the actual representation of the values) should be the same for both charts so as to keep values comparable.